# global variable error when using it in library

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I'm running a project in c++, and I collect statistics from all over the files in it (like how much time is spent to retrieve data from disk).

a small example would be the following

`globals.c`

```
int time = 0;
```

and this is the only file where I declare it.

`globals.h`

```
#ifndef GLOBALS
#define GLOBALS
  extern int time;
  #define TIME time++;
#endif
```

in every file I need to count the time I add `#include globals.h` and works fine, but when I try to use this variable in a library , if I 
use `#include globals.h`

when I link the library this gives me a multiple definition error.

The code I use to create the library is:

```
g++ -g -Wall -m64 -O3 -c mylibrary.c 
ar rcs libmylibrary.a
```

The library compiles correctly, but when I link it to the rest of the project I get the error

NB: This is an example of what the project actually is. I inherited it. its original language was c and I could not change the style (macros for functions, global variables, etc)

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?
Thanks!

**edit**
time is just a fake name, as I said this is a small example, in the real project there is no "time" global variable.
I corrected the globals.h file here.

The error I get is the multiple definitions error.

Comment: `extern time;`? Does that compile?

Comment: I doubt `#include globals.h` compiles either

Comment: First of all change it to extern int time. Did you include header into the project that uses the library?

Comment: How does `globals.c` fit in with your library creation?

Comment: Probably your problem comes from where in the linker call you place the library relative to the other libraries in your project. It is tool-chain/compiler dependent on where it is best placed.

Comment: @Galik i don't use it in the library. in the library i just link the globals.h file

Comment: @LPs yes i included the globals.h file